# Connect QPushButton Jambi

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi, jambi

I'm pretty new to Java programming. I wrote the application listed below, but I can't connect the button to my function. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
package com.teat;
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.*;

public class Application 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        QApplication.initialize(args);
        QWidget mainWidget = new QWidget();
        mainWidget.setWindowTitle("Simple Example");
        QHBoxLayout main_layout = new QHBoxLayout();
        mainWidget.setLayout(main_layout);

        QPushButton new_action = new QPushButton("Working");
        new_action.released.connect("Tata()");
        main_layout.addWidget(new_action);

        SumNum(5,3);
        mainWidget.show();
        QApplication.execStatic();
        QApplication.shutdown();
    }

    private static int SumNum(int num1,int num2)
    {
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;

    }
    private static void Tata(){
        System.out.println("Yes, it's Working");
    }

}
```

When I call the function like `SumNum(5,3);` it works perfectly, but when I call it from button, It don't work. I'm using `new_action.released.connect("Tata()");`

I've looked into Qt, it's giving me
`void com.trolltech.qt.QSignalEmitter.AbstractSignal.connect(Object receiver, String method)` but what is Object receiver?

I even give itself as object receiver, `new_action.released.connect(new_action,"Tata()");` but, nope, it didn't work either.

Any idea?

**Edit:** here the same application in python:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple Example')

        main_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        new_action = QtGui.QPushButton("Working")
        new_action.released.connect(self.Tata)
        main_layout.addWidget(new_action)

        self.show()

    def SumNum(self, num1, num2):
        print num1+num2
        return num1+num2

    def Tata(self):
        print "Yes, it's Working"


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in Python it didn't ask for Object receiver, and it's just run it, but in java it seems like completely different.

Comment: Qt is meant to be used inside the event loop, so that may be the problem. By event loop, I mean the loop that is started by `execStatic()` here. Easy way to do this is to subclass QWidget and use that as `mainWidget`. So there will still be `mainWidget.show()` and `QApplication.execStatic()`, but all other application code is inside the application.

Comment: @Smar i edited my question, added python example, as you said, i have to make separate class and execute it from main class, just like how  it is in python example, right? also what about object receiver? what is that for?

Comment: I see you managed to solve your problem :) Is there any open questions still? If not, please just accept your answer after you’re able to :)

Comment: @Smar yeah, thanks for the help, i'm sure i will have more question later on. :D (also i have to wait 21 hour then i can accept my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as what Smar said, it needed to run in a loop, so i extend from `QWidget`, initial the settings in `Application()`, setup the layout in `initUI()` and run it in `main()`.

```
import com.trolltech.qt.core.*;
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.*;

public class Application extends QWidget {

    public Application() {

        setWindowTitle("Simple Example");
        setMinimumHeight(100);
        setMinimumWidth(100);
        setGeometry(250, 250, 350, 100);

        initUI();

        show();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        QHBoxLayout main_layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

        QPushButton new_action = new QPushButton("Working");
        new_action.released.connect(this,"Tata()");
        main_layout.addWidget(new_action);

    }

    private void Tata(){
        System.out.println("Yes, it's Working");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QApplication.initialize(args);
        new Application();
        QApplication.execStatic();
        QApplication.shutdown();
    }
}
```

since i extended from `QWidget`, i only need to set the layout like so `QHBoxLayout main_layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);` Notice the **this**
as well as connecting the button `new_action.released.connect(this,"Tata()");` Object receiver is this or in another word current `QWidget`

it's exactly same as Python, just python use `self` and Java use `this`.

that's what worked for me, hope that help however having the same problem.